# real time form validation using jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I would like to create a form that validates each field if the user looses focus on a field.

So for example, a user may focus on the username field, not fill anything in and then tab out.

I've come across this jQuery plugin http://jqueryvalidation.org/

However it only seems to work when a user clicks the submit button.

Has anyone manipulated it so that it will do it will validate the form before the submit button is pressed?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There might be a better way to do this, but you can use the `.valid()` function on blur to trigger validation on your inputs when the user exits the field.

```
$('input').on('blur', function() {
    $(this).valid();
});
```

[.valid()](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid)

Note: You will need to call `.validate()` on your form before you can use the `valid()` function, which you should be doing already if it works on submit.